# Start Calibre, update feeds, transfer files and close

Tags: calibre, rss

I want to use Calibre for subscribing to RSS feeds, download new articles and bundle them in `.mobi` files. These files should be send to my Kindle via mail.

Both these processes work without problems, but I do not want to have Calibre running all the time.

Are there command line parameters that allow me to let Calibre only fetch the feeds and send them to my Kindle and then close?

I know I could just let start Calibre after booting and then close it manually, but an automatized version would be nicer.

Comment: There are a number of third party services that can take care of exactly this workflow for you. I use Instapaper, but there are others. Fetching RSS feeds and emailing the mobi files to my device is a supported feature. This or a similar service may be easier in the long run than running the conversion process yourself.

Comment: @Caleb I know of these services, but so far I do not know of any free services that preserve images and actually subscribe to the feed. In Instapaper every article must be added manually instead of subscribing the feed only once.

Comment: I don't see what I was looking for now either. There are third party (e.g. Instasciber) and external automaters (e.g. IFTTT) that can make this happen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it easily from `cron` (if you are on *nix) and most probably it can be done on Windows too. Calubre includes several command line tools, but for you the most important is `ebook-convert(.exe)`.

With that you can create a mobi ebook from the RSS recipe like:

```
ebook-convert WHATEVER.recipe WHATEVER.mobi
```

Mailing can then be done like:

```
calibre-smtp -a WHATEVER.mobi -u SENDERNAME@PROVIDER.com -p PASSWORD -r smtp.PROVIDER.com --port 587 SENDERNAME@PROVIDER.com USERNAME@free.kindle.com ''
```

And set up a cron/scheduler job to automail it to you.

[I'd recommend to read the fine manual.](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/cli/ebook-convert.html)

(***Note:*** this wont add the created mobi to your library! But you can do it with the `calibredb` command [as documented here](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/cli/calibredb.html#calibredb-add))

Comment: Thank you. I edited in the command for sending via calibre.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @Tim I forgot the mailing capabilities of Calibre (which I had never used :-) ).